# Jax RS Client calling Microservices -> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I've got the following problem. I have JAX-RS (Glassfisch 5) Microservices, and I wrote a client to retrieve data from my micro services.

Everything was working fine until I moved the client inside my Java EE Web Application Project (front-end).

Exception: https://pastebin.com/vmf0pyTw

GenericClient: https://pastebin.com/MwUjTyx5

UserStoryClient extends GenericClient:

```html
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class UserStoryClient extends GenericClient<UserStory>{
    public UserStoryClient() {
        super(Consts.USERSTORY_RESOURCEURI, new GenericType<UserStory>(){}, new GenericType<List<UserStory>>(){});
    }

    public Optional<List<UserStory>> getByUserId(int id) {
        Response response = this.getResourceWebTarget()
                .path(Consts.USER_RESOURCEURI)
                .path(String.valueOf(id))
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(Response.class);
        return this.retrieveEntityList(response);
    }
}
```

```html
@RequestScoped
@Named
@Getter @Setter
public class IssueCreateBoundary implements Serializable {
    UserStory userStory = new UserStory();
    @Inject UserStoryClient userStoryGroup;
    private Integer priorityRating;    
    private Integer riskRating;    

    public void submitIssue(){
        if(priorityRating != null)   userStory.setPriority(priorityRating.byteValue());
        if(riskRating != null) userStory.setRisk(riskRating.byteValue());
        
        Optional<UserStory> resp = this.userStoryGroup.create(userStory);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/1kZxNCKQ

When I'm calling the client inside my Test Packages, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem by changing the JSON parser and adding JsonFormat(..) to all my Date's